# Heart-shaped quine

Tags: popularity-contest, quine

As you may or may not know, Valentine's day is getting close. So today, my task for you is:

## Write a heart-shaped quine

Rules:

- Code should look like an identifyable heart shape, i.e. Has two round parts on top and a pointy bottom. It does NOT have to be filled in, but this is not disallowed.
- Standard Quine rules apply (no opening/reading files, etc)
- This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so try to be as creative as possible in your solutions!

---

The closing date will be the day **after** valentine's day (15th of February), 12:00 UTC

Comment: [_A popularity contest must always include an objective validity criterion_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info). The validity criterion _identifyable heart shape. It doesn't have to be perfect, but make sure it resembles a heart_ is clearly not objective

Comment: @LuisMendo Updated to be more specific. If this is still not sufficient, feel free to suggest changes.

Comment: @Martmists I do not think `round` and `pointy` are really objective with regards to text ...

Comment: [tag:popularity-contests] are (ironically) not very popular these days, simply because they're very hard to define in a way that is objective while also allowing for variation in answers.

Comment: Title suggestion: *A program that only loves itself*

Comment: What you could do is to define a series of heart shapes (most likely increasing in size) and defining "looks like a heart" as "matches non-white border characters with one of the following hearts". Just an idea, though.

Comment: [from a perl quine](https://tio.run/##JcrBCoNADATQe75iCIHsHhpbiqdlP6F/IIgHDwWpWpdif75xpacZ3swyvqfWHdJnANIZrQHb8NUqaqRZLVQvWZj2ezStFzVpjHgN0sckjRQmmI6fYfovAEtB4phqxelnIpH7b17Kc35tfnm0dr0d)

Comment: [Joke answer](https://tio.run/##S07MK0ss/v//0cyl//8DAA). Has two round parts on top and a pointy bottom. The heart is filled in.